# Angular2: Dynamic load component Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got an weird error with dynamic component loading in Angular.
I create a form stepper, with 5 steps. Each step is a component and there is a general one to inject them when it's needed.

```
class CreateComponent {
    // List of components i want to inject
    private _ContainerContractComponent = [
        ContractCivilStatusComponent,
        ContractLegalResponsableComponent,
        ContractBulletinComponent,
        ContractPaymentComponent,
        ContractSocialSecurityComponent
    ];
    // List of var i want to inject
    private _currentStudent: StudentInterface;
    private _candidature: CandidatureInterface;
    private _childObserver: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    // My step (numberBetween<1,5>)
    private _stepperStep: number;

    // My loading function
    displayContractPartComponent() {
        let componentFactory = this._componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
            this._ContainerContractComponent[this._stepperStep - 1]
            );
        this.dynamicComponentContainer.clear();
        let componentRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer.createComponent(componentFactory);
        componentRef.instance.candidature = this._candidature;
        componentRef.instance.student = this._currentStudent;
        componentRef.instance.childObserver = this._childObserver;
    }
}
```

To each loaded components i pass 3 var: candidature, student, childObserver.

Everything work's good until this morning, the compiler always pop me this error:

> Error in CreateComponent: The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>
> Type argument candidate 'ContractBulletinComponent' is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'ContractCivilStatusComponent'.
>
> Property '_model' is missing in type 'ContractCivilStatusComponent'.

It's weird because the last line (Property '_model' ...) change each round of complilation and the name of the Component too (here 'ContractBulletinComponent').

I'm searching untill this morning but i've got no idea when it can be coming from, so maybe anyone of you can help-me.
Thank's

Comment: this code has something to do with generics, yet I there are none in the code you posted, are you sure this is where it fails?

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to use the ContactBulletinComponent type where ContractCivilStatusComponent type would be expected. And since the first is not a child of the second compilation fails. I don't see where in your code this could happen.

Comment: Can you try `let componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = `

Comment: @toskv yes, i think it's something like that but what it's strange, why it ask to declare properties in ContractCivilStatusComponent that are private in other component (for exemple here: '_model' in ContractBulletinComponent). If it just want a child of a component type, it weird to ask to implements private variable in the parents (even more that all the components have nothing to share, excepts the 3 variables)

Comment: i found the part of my code who launch the error. In my last component, ContractSocialSecurityComponent, when i try to add a new variable, it launch me this error. But with all others components, who already implements other private variables, i don't have this comportement. i'm still searching why.

Comment: @bishop I remember that they changed the dcl notation like this from beta to rc. I'll post it as an answer when I find the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution, The probem is when i declare my array of component:

```
private _ContainerContractComponent = [
    ContractCivilStatusComponent,
    ContractLegalResponsableComponent,
    ContractBulletinComponent,
    ContractPaymentComponent,
    ContractSocialSecurityComponent
];
```

I need to add the type Array-any to it, like this:

```
private _ContainerContractComponent: Array<any> = [
  ContractCivilStatusComponent,
  ContractLegalResponsableComponent,
  ContractBulletinComponent,
  ContractPaymentComponent,
  ContractSocialSecurityComponent
];
```